# Sysout list of files and transfer files from a directory in java

Tags: java, sockets, streaming

I'm trying to figure out how to get a list of files on the server and how to download them individually. Can anyone guide me in the right direction?

I'm getting file permissions error or (is a directory errors), thanks

UPDATE: 
The error is

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: /myClientFiles (Permission denied)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:213)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:101)
at 
xxxxxxpackegename.com.fr(Client.java:38)
```

Client.java

```
public class Client {

 private static final int PORT = 2665;
 private static String HOST = "localhost";

public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException, IOException {


    int filesize = 5000000;   //buffer size 5mb
    int bytesRead;
    int currentTotalNumberOfBytes = 0;

     //connect to port on server - server waits for this after running socket.accept() in the Server class
    Socket socket = new Socket(HOST, PORT);  

    byte[] byteArray = new byte[filesize];   //create a byte array of 5mb        
    InputStream inputStream = socket.getInputStream();  //channel to write to server
    FileOutputStream fileOutStream = new FileOutputStream("/myClientFiles");      
    BufferedOutputStream bufferOutStream = new BufferedOutputStream(fileOutStream);

    bytesRead = inputStream.read(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);
    currentTotalNumberOfBytes = bytesRead;


    do { //read till the end and store total in bytesRead and add it to currentTotalNumberOfBytes
        bytesRead = inputStream.read(byteArray, currentTotalNumberOfBytes, (byteArray.length-currentTotalNumberOfBytes)); 
        if(bytesRead >= 0) currentTotalNumberOfBytes += bytesRead; 
        }while(bytesRead > -1); // when bytesRead == -1, there's no more data left and we exit the loop


    bufferOutStream.write(byteArray, 0 , currentTotalNumberOfBytes); //write the bytes to the file

    bufferOutStream.flush(); 
    bufferOutStream.close(); 
    socket.close(); 



 }


}
```

Server.java

```
ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(2665);

    Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();                  
    System.out.println("Connected to: " + socket);

    //File transferFile = new File("Allcrisis.doc");              //get local file

    File[] transferFiles = new File("/myServerFiles").listFiles(); //array to store pathnames of files in myServerFiles folder

    byte[] bytearray = new byte[(int)transferFiles.length];  


    for(File file: transferFiles){    
    //FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(transferFiles); 
    FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
    BufferedInputStream butterInputStream = new    BufferedInputStream(fileInputStream); 
    butterInputStream.read(bytearray, 0, bytearray.length); 


    OutputStream outStream = socket.getOutputStream();                
    System.out.println("Sending...");                    
    outStream.write(bytearray, 0, bytearray.length);                

    outStream.flush();   
    }



    socket.close();
```

Comment: Does `mkdir /myClientFiles` work in a command prompt?

Comment: The the folder already exists

Comment: (Whoops, I meant `touch /myClientFiles`, but `mkdir` gives the answer anyway)

Comment: You can't open a `FileOutputStream` for a folder. A `FileOutputStream` can only write to a file, and a file can't have the same path as a folder.

Answer (score 0):

You have a folder `/myClientFiles`.

Your code contains

```
new FileOutputStream("/myClientFiles")
```

which attempts to open a `FileOutputStream` to write to that folder. You can't write to a folder.

You might want to pass `new FileOutputStream` the path to the *file* to write to.